# The calculation of sky surface brightness based on the apparent magnitude of the light source

Tags: sunlight, sun

I am wandering aimlessly to find the proper formula, which would calculate the sky surface brightness in any direction based on:

- apparent magnitude of the light source
- angular distance from the light source
- position of the light source (both above and below the horizon ).

If we assume, that for the solar magnitude of -26.77 the brightness of civil twilight (solar depression of 6 degrees) is about 4 lux. What brightness could be if the solar apparent magnitude was -25 Mag for example?

How to calculate the brightness of civil twilight in an antisolar direction?

**UPDATE:**

I am NOT neglecting the Earth's atmosphere diffusion.
I am looking for a computation of Earth's atmosphere diffusion too, but I know that it's some constant value computed for dry atmosphere.

Comment: I think you are neglecting the main factor in your question: atmospheric diffusion. On the Moon the sky is pitch black except when you are looking directly at the sun. So sky brightness is not only a function of source magnitude, position and distance.

Comment: Have you tried: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=brightness

Comment: And it depends on the properties of the sun, especially if "*apparent* magnitude" is being used.

Comment: -1 for lack of research. I started with [sky brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_brightness) where I found [Airglow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airglow)  which has what appears to be equations for calculating airglow. Noticing your desire for civil twilight, I [expanded my search](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/airglow) and found information about measurements at civil twilight. You're asking for a mighty specific detail and the results will only be valid on Earth. Contrary to popular belief, Science can't reliably calculate the truth about fictional exoplanets.

Comment: @L.Dutch no I am not neglecting. Just looking for a factor of atmosphere diffusion too.

Comment: @JBH Yes, for Earth but later potentially for Mars too.

Comment: @JBH I did the research, so I am sorry to hear that you are giving me -1 for the legitimate question, on which nodoby can answer. I am not after airglow but the dependency of sky surface brightness from the position and apparent brightness of the Sun. If you think, that I haven't done proper research it means, that it's something, that I don't know yet, but you know already (references, links, formulas, etc).

Comment: @Geographos A legitimate question would include the research you found and an explanation for why it was insufficient for your needs. Based on your question, I have nothing but your word that you did any research. [Research is required on Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).